# Objects messed up when I re-open the file

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm not an expert in Blender (and sorry for my english), so I'm really having troubles with an issue I'll describe here:

I've modeled a body with every part as a different object.

[image]

I want to sculpt it now, so I applied the scale of each body part.

[image]

The problem is that now, if I close the file and then I re-open it, I find every object completely messed up in scale, location, ecc..
I also tried to apply every transformation but the result is the same.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
I am using Blender 2.91.2
Thank you

Comment: If you want to know more attach your file via https://blend-exchange.com copy -paste given code into your Q to let us see. BTW Do you need keyframes at this stage of work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have keyframed Location, Rotation and Scale values.
To see the issue you don't have to reopen file, just move on Timeline to another frame.

After *Apply* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *All Transforms* you have to set keyframes again <kbd>I</kbd>. Yellow color indicates keyframed value, orange edited/unsaved a change.

What is happening here? When you apply transforms they became to zero and  1 for scale, but unsaved keyframes remember saved value and when you move on timeline or reopen file, they "jump" back, so they are used like twice now.

Comment: Thank you very very much, now it's working! You saved me :)